# WordPress Pages Asking Viewers to Log In

Tags: wordpress

I have been managing a website, doggydocks.com, and about a week and a half ago, the shopping pages on the site began randomly asking viewers to log in in order to see the content. There doesn't seem to be a pattern with devices or even browsers among those who have experienced this.

I've gone through the plugins and haven't found a problem there.  I can't think of what else I should do, especially since I'm not able to replicate the problem. I guess my question is, is there something besides the browsers and plug-ins that could cause such an error? Especially, when in was working fine before.

Comment: Did you or someone else edit something in the `wp-admin` or `wp-includes` directory that you know of?

Comment: HI Deathstorm. No, not that I'm aware of. How might that affect things if something had been changed?

Comment: Well lets see, you've told that the issue is that visitors are being asked to log in to see the content. I assume this is the log-in to the `/wp-admin` area? And if so. The  `wp-admin` directory contains all the files corresponding to the admin area. Since you've checked all the plug-ins a change to one of these files could be causing the problem. But another cause of the problem could be that there has been made a change to the `page-template` file.

Comment: Thx Deathstorm. I'll dig into that and see what I can find.